# Python subprocess module unable to get the complete command list from ps output

Tags: linux, python-2.7, subprocess

I am using below code to get the output of command "ps -ef | grep java"

```
import subprocess
pp1=subprocess.Popen(["ps" , "-ef"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pp2=subprocess.Popen(['grep','java.util'],stdin=pp1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=pp2.communicate()
print out
```

But it gives only the first line of result, not the complete command line.

```
Current Output:
root    17363     1 16 03:13 ?        01:53:26 /opt/java/jdk7/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/tomcat7//conf/logging.properties -server -Xms6144m -\n
Expected Output:
root    17363     1 16 03:13 ?        01:55:40 /opt/java/jdk7/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/tomcat7//conf/logging.properties -server -Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=2000000000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=2000000000 -Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold=15 -Dsun.reflect.noInflation=true -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/logs/gclog-20151006T0313 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9003 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/conf/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/conf/jmxremote.access -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/tomcat7//endorsed -classpath /opt/tomcat/tomcat7//bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/tomcat7//bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat/tomcat7/ -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/tomcat7/ -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/tomcat7//temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Can someone tell me how to get the complete command line.

Comment: Does it work from the command line?

Comment: Running `grep` in Python, when Python itself is eminently and idiomatically able to do `if 'java.util' in line:` is rather back-asswards.

Comment: First its not runnung from anywhere, i am using it in python shell itself.... and it is not working..
Output of first statement ps -ef  is also not complete, the cmd of ps output  is not coming completely in python subprocess and this is happening only for multiline cmd only, Those cmds of ps output are one line is working fine.